# Get full name of the enum C#

Tags: c#, enums

**Sample Code:**

```
    public enum FruitTypeIs
    {
       Orange,
       Mango,
       Banana
    }

    public void WriteFruitType(FruitTypeIs fruitType)
    {
        string fruitTypeIs = typeof(FruitTypeIs) + "." + fruitType.ToString(); // -> FruitTypeIs.Mango
        Console.WriteLine($"{fruitTypeIs}");
    }
```

In the above sample code, I want to print the received enum value alongwith the enum type. For example, if I receive `Mango` as the value to the parameter `FruitTypeIs fruitType` then, I want to print the full value `FruitTypeIs.Mango`. Since new Fruit types could be added to the enum so, I cannot have a if/switch statement.

As a workaround I can use the statement `string fruitTypeIs = typeof(FruitTypeIs) + "." + fruitType.ToString();`, which is working fine but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `ConsoleWriteLine($"{nameof(FruitTypeIs)}.{fruitType}")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest implementing a *generic* method

```
// static - we don't need instance (this) here
// generic - T - suits for any Enum, not necessary FruitTypeIs
public static string FullEnumName<T>(T value) where T : Enum =>
  $"{typeof(T).Name}.{Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value)}";
```

usage:

```
var value = FruitTypeIs.Mango;

...

Console.Write(FullEnumName(value));
```

You can implement it as an *extension method*, e.g.

```
public static class EnumExtensions {
  public static string FullEnumName<T>(this T value) where T : Enum =>
    $"{value.GetType().Name}.{Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value)}";
}
```

and then put it

```
Console.Write(FruitTypeIs.Mango.FullEnumName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try extension, add an extension for `Enum`

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static string GetFullType(this Enum e) => $"{e.GetType().Name}.{e}";
}
```

then you can use this in your code

```
Console.WriteLine(FruitTypeIs.Banana.GetFullType());
```